# Prove that $XY$ always passes through the orthocenter of triangle $\triangle ABC$

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

Given triangle $\triangle ABC$. Any circle with center $J$ passing through $BC$ intersects $AC$ and $AB$ at $E$ and $F$ respectively. Let $X$ be the point such that triangle $\triangle XBF$ is similar to $\triangle JCE$ ($X$, $C$ are on the same side of $AB$). Let $Y$ be the point such that triangle $\triangle YCE$ is similar to triangle $\triangle JBF$ ($Y$, $B$ are on the same side of $AC$). Prove that $XY$ always passes through the orthocenter of triangle $\triangle ABC$.

I'm preparing for maths exam in high school, but I can't find out any clue, please help me, I appreciate any help!

[image]

Comment: I don't find it at all clear where X and Y are supposed to lie from the verbal description. I also assume the diagram is made by you based on the word description. Given any point inside triangle ABC, how do you define if it's on the same side as AB or AC? Are X and Y supposed to lie inside the triangle, or can it lie outside?

Comment: Do you mean $\overline{HY}$?  The altitude of $\overline{AB}$ does not cross $\overline{XY}$ (and neither does the perpendicular bisector of $\overline{AB}$).

Comment: I’m sorry, i mean “X,C is on the same side of AB” and “Y,B is also on the side of AC”

Answer (score 1):

Before i started any thoughts in the direction of solving the question, i was needing a way to construct the figure. My figure looks low with a lot of unneeded and a few needed points as follows:

[image: mse question 4791509]

Now i need some time to explain the notations, and how $X, Y$ were constructed. Solution starts later, when the actors have their clear roles.

We start with $\Delta ABC$ with orthocenter $H$, and let $J$ be a point on the perpendicular bisector $\alpha$ of $BC$. Let us denote by $z$ the (signed) measure of the angles in $B,C$ of $\Delta JBC$ (which is isosceles). The points $E\in AC$ and $F\in AB$
are chosen so that $E\ne C$, $F\ne B$, and the circle centered in $J$ with radius $JB=JC$ passes through $E,F$. Let us use $2x$, $2y$ for the measures of the angles in $J$ in $\Delta JCE$ and $\Delta JBF$.
A prime decoration of a point $Z$ denotes the point $Z'$ which is the projection of $Z$ on $AB$.
A double prime (second) decoration of a point $Z$ denotes the point $Z''$ which is the projection of $Z$ on $AC$.
From now on we will no longer need $E,F$. More relevant are the points
$J',J''$. We have $x=\widehat{J''JC}$, $y=\widehat{J'JB}$.
Working in $\Delta BJJ'$ and $\Delta CJJ''$ we see that $x,y$ are in relation to $z$, and to the data of $\Delta ABC$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
x &= 90^\circ-\widehat{JCJ''}=90^\circ-(C+z)\ ,\\
y &= 90^\circ-\widehat{JBJ'}=90^\circ-(B+z)\ ,\\
\end{aligned}
$$
We will use for this triangle the conventional notations, $A,B,C$ also for the angles (instead of $\hat A, \hat B, \hat C$), $a,b,c$ for the sides (lengths), $h_a,h_b,h_c$ for the heights (lengths), $R$ for the circumradius. Let also $R_J$ denote the length $R_J=JB=JC=\frac a2\cos z$.

The points $X,Y$ were constructed as follows (to have the OP property).
Let $E_1$ be the reflection of $E$ w.r.t. the perpendicular bisector $\alpha$.
We draw a parallel to $JE_1$ through $F$, it intersects $BJ$ in a yellow point, take it together with $B,F$, draw the circle through these three points, and intersect this circle with the angle bisector $JJ'$ of $\widehat{BJF}$. There are two intersection points, we make the choice as in the figure, the yellow bulled is denoted by $X$ in the figure. Then the angle $2x$ from $\widehat {CJE}=\widehat {BJE_1}$ is thus transferred through the first yellow point to the second yellow point $X$. A similar construction was done for $Y$.

So far we have only a valid picture in geogebra.
And geogebra confirms optically the colinearity of $H,X,Y$.
What about a proof?

---

The proof i can type is unfortunately analytic. Well, one can use vectors instead, but we are not working in a synthetic manner.
We break, organize the plane w.r.t. two directions, $JJ'$ and $JJ''$.
Each point $Z$ has two coordinates w.r.t. these axes, we build parallels to the named axes $JJ''$ and $JJ'$, each parallel intersects the "other" axis in a point, and we read off the coordinates $(Z_{JJ'}, Z_{JJ''})$ obtained in this manner. For instance, $J=(0,0)$, and $X=(JX,0)$, and $Y=(0,JY)$.
(The sign must be taken carefully in $JX,JY$, we use oriented axes $JJ'$ and $JJ''$.)

It remains to compute all coordinates of the points $H,X,Y$ explicitly, and verify the colinearity, which translates algebraically as a linear (affine) dependency.
The point $H$ is the more complicated ingredient. Which is the component of $H$ on $JJ'$? We can read it on $JJ'$, but we can also read it off on any parallel to this line. The parallel through $J''$ is such a line,
it is the one first height in $\Delta BJ''A$,
and we intersect it with a second height
$BH''\|JJ''$, and measure the part of this first height between the parallels
$BH''\|JJ''$. So we need the distance between $J''$ and the orthocenter
$\Phi:=H_{\Delta BJ''A}$ of the triangle in the index. I need a new picture for this isolated situation:

[image: mse 4791509 second picture]

The component of $H$ on $JJ'$ is the one orange segment, it is congruent to the other orange segment $J''\Phi$, so it is
$$
\begin{aligned}
\Phi J''
&=\frac{H''J''}{\cos \Phi J''H''}=\frac{H''J''}{\sin A}\ ,\\
\Phi J''\sin A
&=
H'' J''= BJ\cos\underbrace{\sphericalangle(BJ,H''J'')}_{y+(90^\circ-A)}
= R_J\cos (C-z)
\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
(Above $y$ is seen as $\widehat{BJJ'}$ and $(90^\circ-A)$ as
$\widehat{\Phi J''H''}$.)
The other component is easily transposed in a formula.

So let us compute in detail. In $\Delta XBJ$ the sine theorem gives
$JX:JB$ as $\sin\widehat {JBX} :\sin \widehat {JXB}$. So
$$
\begin{aligned}
JX 
&=R_J\frac {\sin(B-C)}{\cos(C+z)}\ ,
\qquad\text{ and similarly }\\
JY &= R_J\frac {\sin(C-B)}{\cos(B+z)}\ .\text{ So we have the needed components:}
\\[2mm]
H &=\frac 1{\sin A}(H''J''\ ,\ H'J')
=\frac {R_J}{\sin A}(\ \cos (C-z)\ ,\ \cos (B-z)\ )\ ,\\
X &=(JX, 0)=R_J\left( \ \frac {\sin(B-C)}{\cos(C+z)}\ ,\ 0\ \right)\ ,\\
Y &=(0, JY)=R_J\left( \ 0\ ,\ \frac {\sin(C-B)}{\cos(B+z)}\ \right)\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
It remains to compute the following determinant,
we will use $\sim$ to mark an equality up to some known factor.
$$
\begin{aligned}
&
\begin{vmatrix}
1 & H''J''/\sin A & H'J'/\sin A\\
1 & JX & 0 \\
1 & 0 & JY
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad\sim
\begin{vmatrix}
\sin A    & \cos(C-z) & \cos(B-z)\\
\cos(C+z) & \sin(B-C) & 0 \\
\cos(B+z) & 0         & \sin(C-B)
\end{vmatrix}
\\
&\qquad\sim
-\sin A\sin^2(B-C)
+\sin(B-C)(\cos(C-z)\cos(C+z)-\cos(B-z)\cos(B+z))
\\
&\qquad\sim
-2\sin A\sin(B-C)
+\Big((\cos 2C + \cos 2z)-(\cos 2B+\cos 2z)\Big)
\\
&\qquad\sim
-2\sin (B+C)\sin(B-C)
+(\cos 2C -\cos 2B)
\\
&\qquad=0\ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The determinant vanishes, so the points $H,X,Y$ are colinear.

$\square$